# Getting error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

Code:

```
function responsiveSlider() {
jQuery(".slider-bloc").each(function() {
    var a = jQuery(this),
        b = this;
    if (1 != a.data("is_slider")) {
        a.data("is_slider", 1);
        var c = a.find(".nav-slider .item-nav"),
            d = jQuery(a.find(".content-rel-slider")[0]),
            e = jQuery(a.find(".content-abs-slider")[0]);
        a.find(".item-slider").each(function(a) {
            jQuery(this).attr("data-inc", a + 1)
        }), a.find(".item-slider").clone().appendTo(e), a.find(".item-slider").clone().appendTo(e);
        var f = a.find(".item-slider"),
            g = a.hasClass("full-slider"),
            h = 0,
            i = function(a) {
                e.css({
                    width: "100%"
                }), g && f.css({
                    width: d.width()
                }), e.css({
                    width: jQuery(f[0]).width() * f.length
                });
                Math.ceil(d.width() / jQuery(f[0]).width());
                f.length * jQuery(f[0]).width() < d.width() ? e.css({
                    left: 0
                }) : 0 == a && e.css({
                    left: -jQuery(f[0]).width()
                })
            },
            j = function(b) {
                var c = Math.ceil(d.width() / jQuery(f[0]).width());
                durationanim = 2 >= c ? 300 : 800;
                var g = jQuery(f[0]).width();
                if (b + c - 1 >= f.length ? b = 0 : 0 > b && (b = f.length - c), f[b]) {
                    if (f.length * g < d.width()) return;
                    if (a.hasClass("moving")) return;
                    a.addClass("moving"), a.find(".item-slider").removeClass("current"), jQuery(a.find(".item-slider")[1]).addClass("current");
                    var i = "next",
                        j = 1,
                        k = e.position().left,
                        l = -g * c - g;
                    if (1 > b) {
                        i = "prev";
                        for (var m = 0; c > m; m++) jQuery(a.find(".item-slider")[f.length - 1]).prependTo(e);
                        k -= g * c, l = -g
                    } else j += c;
                    f = a.find(".item-slider"), h = 1;
                    var o = e.find(".item-slider.current").index();
                    if (!isMobile && c > 1) {
                        "next" == i ? (initforfirstslide = o, lastforfirstslide = o + c - 1, initforsecondslide = o + c, lastforsecondslide = o + 2 * c - 1) : (initforfirstslide = o - c, lastforfirstslide = o - 1, initforsecondslide = o, lastforsecondslide = o + c - 1);
                        for (var m = initforfirstslide; m <= lastforfirstslide; m++) {
                            var p = durationanim / 2,
                                q = durationanim / 2;
                            "next" == i ? movexfirstslide = -jQuery(f[m]).width() * (c - (m - o + 1)) / 4 : movexfirstslide = jQuery(f[m]).width() * (m - o + 1) / 4;
                            var r = new TimelineLite({
                                paused: !0
                            });
                            r.fromTo(jQuery(f[m]), p / 1e3, {
                                x: 0,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }, {
                                x: movexfirstslide,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }), r.to(jQuery(f[m]), q / 1e3, {
                                x: 0,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }), r.play()
                        }
                        for (var m = initforsecondslide; m <= lastforsecondslide; m++) {
                            var p = durationanim / 2,
                                q = durationanim / 2;
                            "next" == i ? movexsecondslide = jQuery(f[m]).width() * (m - o - c + 1) / 4 : movexsecondslide = jQuery(f[m]).width() * (m - o + 1) / 4;
                            var r = new TimelineLite({
                                paused: !0
                            });
                            r.fromTo(jQuery(f[m]), p / 1e3, {
                                x: 0,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }, {
                                x: movexsecondslide,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }), r.to(jQuery(f[m]), q / 1e3, {
                                x: 0,
                                force3D: !0,
                                ease: Cubic.easeInOut
                            }), r.play()
                        }
                    }
                    if (TweenMax.fromTo(e, durationanim / 1e3, {
                            left: k,
                            force3D: !0,
                            ease: n
                        }, {
                            left: l,
                            force3D: !0,
                            ease: n,
                            onComplete: function() {
                                if ("next" == i) {
                                    h--;
                                    for (var b = 0; c > b; b++) jQuery(a.find(".item-slider")[0]).appendTo(e);
                                    e.css({
                                        left: -g
                                    })
                                }
                                f.removeClass("current"), jQuery(f[1]).addClass("current"), f = a.find(".item-slider"), a.removeClass("moving")
                            }
                        }), a.find(".nav-bullet").length > 0) {
                        var s = a.find(".nav-bullet .bullet").length - 1,
                            t = jQuery(a.find(".item-slider")[j]).attr("data-inc"),
                            u = t * s / (f.length / 4);.5 == u && (u = .4), currentbullet = Math.round(u), a.find(".nav-bullet .bullet").removeClass("current"), jQuery(a.find(".nav-bullet .bullet")[currentbullet]).addClass("current")
                    }
                }
            };
        c.each(function() {
            var a = jQuery(this);
            a.on({
                click: function() {
                    var b = a.hasClass("prev-button") ? 0 : 2;
                    return j(b), !1
                }
            })
        }), _touchstart = !1, swipedirection = !1, _lastcoord = 0, coord = 0, initmoveposition = 0, touchmove = !1;
        var k = new Hammer(b),
            l = e.position().left,
            m = l,
            n = Cubic.easeInOut;
        k.on("panstart", function(b) {
            a.hasClass("moving") || (n = Strong.easeOut, l = e.position().left, m = l)
        }), k.on("panend", function(b) {
            a.hasClass("moving") || (2 == b.direction && j(1), 4 == b.direction && j(0), 1 == b.direction && TweenMax.to(e, .6, {
                left: m,
                force3D: !0,
                ease: Strong.easeOut,
                throwProps: !0
            }))
        }), k.on("panleft panright", function(b) {
            a.hasClass("moving") || (0 == l && (l = e.position().left), TweenMax.to(e, .6, {
                left: l + b.deltaX,
                force3D: !0,
                ease: Strong.easeOut,
                throwProps: !0
            }))
        }), jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {
            i(!1)
        }), jQuery(a.find(".item-slider")[f.length - 1]).appendTo(e), e.css({
            left: -jQuery(f[0]).width() * (h + 1)
        }), f = a.find(".item-slider"), jQuery(f[1]).addClass("current"), h++, i(!0)
    }
})}
```

This is the code of my responsive slider but sometimes it gave me the error 
`l = e.position().left,` on this line, i tried to remove this line but then slider stops working, i don't know why sometimes it doesn't gave me the error please explain this to me will be very thankful to you.

Comment: explicity define your variables

Comment: We need to know what is `e`

Comment: `position()` of e is `undefined` so your problem is in variable `e` or in function `position()`

Comment: It is extremely clear `e.position()` or `e` is undefined...

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding i have added full code of my slider I hope it helps.

Comment: if you console.log `e` what do you get?  you also seem to be overriding your `a` var: `var a = jQuery(this)` and `i = function(a) {`

Comment: It means that sometimes `jQuery(a.find(".content-abs-slider")[0]);` returns empty jq matched set. You have to investigate why

Answer (score 0):

Just place this line :

`var e = jQuery(a.find(".content-abs-slider")[0]);`

after or within
`j = function(b) {`